# Build WAR file from Graddle Project on InteliJ IDEA Community (excluding resources from build)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, war

I developed a Spring Application using InteliJ IDEA community version.

Community edition don't have support to WAR artifacts, so I have to get it manually.

I've found how to do it on maven projects, but mine is a graddle project. So, how can I build a WAR from my graddle project?

In maven projects you can configure a maven run that uses **wagon-maven-plugin** in order to obtain a WAR file. Is it possible to make the same with graddle?

**EDIT**

I've been testing with bootWar and bootJar in order to make both (Jar and War).

Ok, it worked. My problem now is that these two pluguins are actually packing my *resources* diretory.

I've tried to use exclude but it didn't worked.

Thats what i'm doing:

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'Server.Application'
    exclude("/src/resources/**")
    version =  '0.1.7'
}

bootWar {
    mainClassName = 'Server.Application'
    exclude("/src/resources/**")
    version = '0.1.3'
}
```

And my project structure is like:

- libs
- src

  - main

    - java
    - Server
    - resources

**EDIT 2** - Final aproach

In order to keep the resouces out of the build I delete them before building:

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'FitServer.Application'
    setDestinationDir(new File ('build/war'))
    version = '0.1.2'

    doFirst {
        delete('build/resources')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Gradle Guide](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/) there is a `war plugin` for building Java web applications, and the community supplies an excellent plugin called `gretty` for testing and deploying web applications on Jetty or Tomcat.

You can use this war plugin in `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I tried to use bootJar and bootWar and it worked but i cannot exclude resources from build.